# What’s the meaning of “try and act”?

Tags: meaning

When you hear the phrase “Try and act”, How do you paraphrase it? Is this expression common among native speakers?

Comment: Lacks context.  It could be a semi-legitimate combo of "try out and act" in a theatrical context, or it could be the sort of slang version of "try to act" that is often heard.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually, there is no context, because it’s used as a kind of SLOGAN for students’ research activities at  a high school I work for. I wondered if this phrase is good as a slogan. That’s why I asked. Thank you!